# Cuda - compile local and run remote

Tags: linux, cuda, nvidia, remote-debugging, drivers

I want to compile my program locally and next run on server, because I haven't cuda capable graphics card.

My computer:

- Kubuntu 12.04 x32
- Nvidia display driver - lack
- Nvcc - v6.01
- Gcc - 4.6.3

Server:

- Ubuntu 13.10 x64
- Graphics card - GF GTX 480
- Nvidia display driver - 337.xx
- Nvcc - v6.01
- Gcc - 4.8.1

Compilation on local computer:

```
nvcc kernel.cu
```

Running on server:

```
./a.out
```

But I get following error - "Cuda driver version is insufficient for cuda runtime version."
What's wrong? When I compile my code on server it work without problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be caused by the fact that you compile on x32 but execute on x64 architecture.

This problem is also described here: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/555955/32-bit-executable-fails-with-insufficient-driver-version-on-64-bit-linux-os/

The solution provided there is to install the missing 32bit gcc libraries, which in your case (Ubuntu) should possible through:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```